# Android java module "jar" file dependency issue

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have Android gradle project which consists of main module and a pure java library. The java library has a dependency on a jar file (Gson is shown here for demo purposes only):

[image: tree structure]

The project compiles fine but when I try to run it it fails with `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.Gson
    at com.example.JavaLibClass.javaMethod(JavaLibClass.java:7)
    at com.denisk.deptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
```

If I replace `jar` dependency with regular Maven dependency, it works.

If I move `jar` dependency from `javalib` to `app` and introduce dependency `Gson` dependency in the activity, it works.

**app/build.gradle** dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':javalib')
}
```

**javalib/build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
}
```

**MainActivity**'s `onCreate` (inside `app`):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    JavaLibClass javaLibClass = new JavaLibClass();
    javaLibClass.javaMethod();

}
```

**JavaLibClass** (inside `javalib`):

```
public class JavaLibClass {
    public void javaMethod() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
    }
}
```

Github repository with the demo project:

https://github.com/denisk20/android-gradle-dependency-test

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

---

Edit 1:
It doesn't matter whether I build with Android Studio or with pure Gradle.

Edit 2:
I have have tried it with android gradle plugin `1.4.0-beta4` from AOSP - same error.

Comment: its been a while since i had to use a jar but IIRC you need to list it in your dependency's `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')`, i could be wrong though

Comment: @tyczj than's for the suggestion, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Similar issue in Android issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186012

Comment: i'm facing same kind of issue in eclipse also. in my project targetSdk=23

Answer (score 1):

The class which is failing to load probably has a missing dependency of its own. Annoyingly, the VM in Android 5.1 does not tell you what that dependency is. 
I found that when I ran my app on an older Android 2.3 device with the Dalvik VM, the missing dependency was identified in a log message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Its not a bug actually, instead you need to import the jar file as a dependency in your project. I believe that you just put that Jar file in the lib folder of your project but did not import as dependency in your project. That is why the maven dependency is working fine since it automatically import it. So, go to File>Project Structure, Select your project under module section and on Dependency tab, add your jar file as File dependency by browsing to your lib folder. Now, rebuild your project, It should work fine.

Comment: The dependency is already there once I change `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')`
http://snag.gy/OR12Y.jpg. I have edited the question and listed jar file explicitly in dependencies to avoid confusion.